# How to make a class that extends SurfaceView start an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

So I have a class that draws and does all the lifting in my game, which extends SurfaceView.
I want to start a new Activity that shows the score of the player after he dies. 
The GameOver activity has the score.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

```
Context context = getContext(); // from MySurfaceView/Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameOver.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: just want to add you can pass your game data as well from the SurfaceView to the Activity via the Intent in the example above